# Set multiplicity for user defined classes

Tags: python

I want to use sets on some classes I've made. I want those sets to restrict the multiplicity of my objects of that class. However I have a problem. Consider this toy example:

```
class Thing(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

a = Thing(5)
b = Thing(5)

s = set()
s.add(a)
s.add(b)
print s
```

The output of this code is:

```
set([5, 5])
```

I just assumed that set() would use `__eq__` to determine whether the object should be included, but perhaps it uses `is`. Is there an easy workaround such that the output would just be `set([5])`?

Comment: Also please define `__ne__`, so the != operator works without nasty surprises.

Comment: Thanks Petr, that's a damn good point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the `__hash__` method of your class to return a hashcode based on `value`. 
In other words, you need to make your class *[hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable)*.

```
class Thing(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

a = Thing(5)
b = Thing(5)

s = set()
s.add(a)
s.add(b)
print s
```

Comment: It's usually a much better idea to return `hash(self.value)` in `__hash__()`.  Try `hash(thing("a"))` with your code to see the difference.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Good point. I assumed that the OP is always using `int`s. I'm changing my code. Thanks!